# Why front-channel specification doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, identityserver4, samesite

We have the following environment:

- An IdentityServer4 Implementation as Identity Services Provider.
- 2 Websites built on .Net Core 2.2.8 and that are integrated with Identity.
- Local IIS 10.0.18362.1 on my laptop Windows 10 Pro

Client's configuration on IdentityServer:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "App1",
                ClientId = "App1",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                RequireConsent = false,
                RedirectUris = "https://localhost:5000/siging-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = "https://localhost:5000/home/index",
                FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:5000/home/frontchannellogout",
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                },
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secretApp1".Sha256())
                }
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "App2",
                ClientId = "App2",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                RequireConsent = false,
                RedirectUris = "https://localhost:5001/siging-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = "https://localhost:5000/home/index",
                FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:5001/home/frontchannellogout",
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                },
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secretApp2".Sha256())
                }
            }
```

Client's configuration on clients side:

```
        //For authentication App1
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44329/";
            options.ClientId = "App1";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.Scope.Add(OidcConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
            options.Scope.Add(OidcConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.ClientSecret = "secretApp1";
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.GivenName
            };

            options.ClaimActions.Remove("acr");

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                    {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = $"tenant:{configuration["TenantId"]}";
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/home");
                    context.HandleResponse();

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        });

        //For authentication App2
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44329/";
            options.ClientId = "App2";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.Scope.Add(OidcConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
            options.Scope.Add(OidcConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.ClientSecret = "secretApp2";
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.GivenName
            };

            options.ClaimActions.Remove("acr");

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                    {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = $"tenant:{configuration["TenantId"]}";
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/home");
                    context.HandleResponse();

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        });
```

These are the Logout implementations on both apps:

```
        // Logout App1
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
            HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var disco = await _discoveryCache.GetAsync();
            var postLogoutUrl = "https://localhost:5001/home/index";// I want to go to App2 when I logout from App1
            var urlEndSession = new RequestUrl(disco.EndSessionEndpoint).CreateEndSessionUrl(idToken, postLogoutUrl);
            return Redirect(urlEndSession);
        }

        return View("Index");
    }

        // Logout App2
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
            HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var disco = await _discoveryCache.GetAsync();
            var postLogoutUrl = "https://localhost:5000/home/index"; // I want to go to App1 when I logout from App2
            var urlEndSession = new RequestUrl(disco.EndSessionEndpoint).CreateEndSessionUrl(idToken, postLogoutUrl);
            return Redirect(urlEndSession);
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

These are the FrontChannelLogout implementations on both apps:

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Frontchannellogout(string sid)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var currentSid = User.FindFirst("sid")?.Value ?? "";
            if (string.Equals(currentSid, sid, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                HttpContext.Session.Clear();
                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

We are working to accomplish, that when a user sign out from one App, it's actually login out from the entire system using front-channel specification.

Once you sign-in in the App1 and move to the App2 we have SSO and the user have been signed-in in both apps. Once the user decide to logout from the current app he should be logout from the other app too and Identity Server.

The app(App1) from where I did the logout deleted the cookies as it was supposed to happen, and the identityServer's cookies were deleted too, but the other app(App2) didn't delete its cookies and never hit its frontchannellogout, so I'm still login-in in that second app(App2).

I am aware of the recent change that Google roll-out related with the SameSite cookie option and I am also updated with the information related to a recent rollback of this changes, and even thought I am not 100% sure that is the cause of my problem I think it  might be related with this.  Because of this I have tried a couple of work around solutions that I have found online but so far I haven't succeed,

I used this [Upcoming SameSite Cookie Changes in ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/) as a guideline to resolve my issue. This is my code on both StartUp.cs App1 and App2 classes:

```
        private void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
    {
        if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
        {
            var userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
            if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome/8") || userAgent.Contains("Firefox/7"))
            {
                options.SameSite = (SameSiteMode)(-1);
            }
        }
    }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = (SameSiteMode)(-1);
            options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
                CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
            options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
                CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
        });

        // ... some configurations more like services.AddAuthentication(...) ...
    }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // ... 

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

EDIT: Browser cookie storage

1-) log-in into App1

[image: log-in into App1]

2-) log-in into App2

[image: log-in into App2]

3-) after hit logout from App2 first-step

[image: after hit logout from App2 first-step]

4-) after identityserver redirect to App1 because the postlogoutredirecturi is App1 in App2

[image: after identityserver redirect to App1 because the postlogoutredirecturi is App1 in App2]

Comment: You should see stuff being logged to the console if the browser is refusing to set cookies or if stuff like CSP is preventing the iframes from being loaded. Do you see anything like that?

Comment: I edited the question and attached some images to show cookies in the browser. The browser is Mozilla Firefox 75.0 (64-bit)

Comment: I am also have same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400654/why-identityserver4-provide-send-back-different-cookie-for-each-clients Is this happen because of `SameSite` attribute? @Guille If you solve this problem, please add your findings as answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu I got some kind of solution. In the logout inside the Identityserver I was returning a redirect to the postlogoutredirecturi, like this: return Redirect(vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri), I changed to return a LoggedOut view like this: return View("LoggedOut", vm) where an iframe is rendered with SignOutIframeUrl property of the LoggedOutViewModel, vm. I said I got some kind of solution because even though I allways see the first cookie that app1 set when it login for first time even so app1 is look like it is logged out.

Comment: @Guille Please add your findings as answer. So, I and other community readers get benefits.

Comment: @Guille already I have same code that you mentioned. fyi, I am using `BackChannelLogout` protocol and I didn't receive `sid` when I trigger logout in any of the client application and also I am using `xframe` to block `iframe` in all my app. Are these reasons why logout not working?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu I think maybe you are sending a wrong postLogoutRedirectUri in your logout request to IdentityServer, I mean, when you request to endsession endpoint you need to pass two parameters, idTokenHint and postLogoutRedirectUri, make sure the postLogoutRedirectUri you are passing is the same you have in the identityServer client configuration for that client, I mean, in IdentityServer you have a client configuration in your Config.cs where you set the postLogoutRedirectUri for that particular client you want to make the logout.

Comment: @Guille I am unable to get you what you're saying. Could you please answer my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400654/why-identityserver4-provide-send-back-different-cookie-for-each-clients

Answer (score 0):

I got some kind of solution.

In AccountController/Logout Action inside IdentityServer I was returning a redirect to the postlogoutredirecturi, like this:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{        
//... code before this action

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
    {
        var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

        if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
        }

        if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
        {
            string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

            return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
        }

        // this line was here before I got the problem and I chenged later.
        return Redirect(vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
    }

//... code after this action
 }
```

So, I just change last line to return the LoggedOut view where an iframe is rendered with SignOutIframeUrl property of the LogoutInputModel vm.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{        
//... code before this action

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
    {
        var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

        if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
        }

        if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
        {
            string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

            return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
        }

        // this line is the one solve my problem.
        return View("LoggedOut", vm);
    }

//... code after this action
 }
```

This is the LoggedOut view code:

```
@model LoggedOutViewModel
@{
  // set this so the layout rendering sees an anonymous user
  ViewData["signed-out"] = true;
}
<div id="main-panel" class="mt-5">
    <div class="page-header logged-out text-center">
        <div id="branding-area">
            <img src="~/some_image.svg" alt="gov-easy" class="logo" />
        </div>
        <p class="display-4">You are now being logged out...</p>
        <p>If you are not automatically redirected, click the button below.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mx-auto" id="returnHomeBtn">Return home page</button>
    @if (Model.PostLogoutRedirectUri != null)
    {
        <div class="hidden">
            Click <a class="PostLogoutRedirectUri" href="@Model.PostLogoutRedirectUri">here</a> to return to the
            <span>@Model.client</span> application.
        </div>
    }
    @if (Model.SignOutIframeUrl != null)
    {
        <iframe width="0" height="0" class="signout hidden" src="@Model.SignOutIframeUrl"></iframe>
    }
</div>
</div>
@section scripts
{
@if (Model.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut)
{
    <script src="~/js/signout-redirect.js"></script>
}
}
```

This is the javascript code inside ~/js/signout-redirect.js:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var a = document.querySelector("a.PostLogoutRedirectUri");
    if (a) {
        window.location = a.href;
    }
});

$('#returnHomeBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.PostLogoutRedirectUri').click();
});
```