# Why IdentityServer4 provide/send-back different cookie for each clients?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, identityserver4

I have two mvc client application `mvc_client1` and `mvc_client2`. When I logged into `mvc_client1` and click the menu to launch `mvc_client2` automatically authenticate and open authorized page as per `IdentityServer4` documentation.

But, if I trigger logout from any of the client only logout the client which I requested the logout. I have already read documentation and implemented `Back-Channel-Logout`. Even though single sign-out not working as documented.

I noticed something that, Identity server provide/send-back different cookie value for each client when authorize. Will it causes an single sign-out? *(Please refer attached image)* If yes, how to resolve this?

Or, Is this because of recent `SameSite` update in all modern browsers?

**Client1:**

[image: Client 1]

**Client2:**

[image: Client 2]

### EDIT :

**IdentityServer Project's Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    //...
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityConfiguration.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityConfiguration.GetClients())
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>()
        .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
}
```

**Client Project's Startup:**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
        CookieHttpOnly = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180),
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://localhost:44306/",

        ClientId = "mvc_client1",
        ClientSecret = "secret",
        Scope = "openid profile",
        ResponseType = "code id_token",
        RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44307/",

        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        UseTokenLifetime = false,
        RequireHttpsMetadata = true,

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
            {
                var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                       id,
                       n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },

            RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
            {
                if (IsAjaxRequest(n.Request))
                {
                    n.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    n.Response.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");
                    n.State = NotificationResultState.HandledResponse;
                }

                switch (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType)
                {
                    case Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication:
                        {
                            n.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
                            break;
                        }
                    case Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout:
                        {
                            var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");
                            if (idTokenHint != null)
                            {
                                n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                                n.ProtocolMessage.ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"];
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
}

private bool IsAjaxRequest(IOwinRequest request)
{
    IReadableStringCollection query = request.Query;
    if ((query != null) && (query["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
    return (headers != null) && (headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest");
}
```

**My Client Configuration:**

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() =>
new List<IdentityResource>
{
    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
};

public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() =>
new List<Client> {
    new Client {
        ClientName = "MVC Client 1",
        ClientId = "mvc_client1",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
        },
        RedirectUris = new List<string>
        {
            "https://localhost:44307/"
        },
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
        {
            "https://localhost:44307/"
        },
        AllowedScopes =
        {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
        },
        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
        RequireConsent = false,
        BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired = true,
        BackChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44307/Home/SignoutOidc",
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"ForgetPasswordUri", "https://localhost:44307/account/forgotpassword" },
            {"SubscribeUri", ""https://localhost:44307/account/register" }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Which flow are you using? Also how does your Startup configuration look? It's hard to help when there's little information to work off of. The IdentityServer4 framework shouldn't administer any auth cookies by itself, all cookie management should essentially be done by your endpoints. All they do is register their authentication scheme as default

Comment: @Randy, I have edited my question by added code snippet.

Comment: try to follow this example : https://blog.tretainfotech.com/posts/2018/August/single-sign-out-in-identityserver4-with-back-channel-logout

Comment: @Guille my client apps are in `ASP.NET MVC`. In above url they explained using `.NET Core`. Do you have working sample for `CookieEventHandler` and `LogoutUserManager` in MVC?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu to be honest, I never tried to do it on ASP NET MVC.